# Vue3 objects from Array only rendering after making a small change in component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

ers,

Experiencing a strange rendering issue. I am grabbing user data from localForage located in my Vuex store in a promise in the following component:

```html
<template>
<div>
    <h1>Users available for test {{ $route.params.id }}</h1>
    <v-form>
      <div v-if="this.import_complete">
        <UserList
        :users="users"
        />
    </div>
  </v-form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import UserList from './UserList.vue';

export default {
  name: 'UserManagement',

  components: {
    UserList,
  },

  data: () => ({
    users: [],
    import_complete: false,
  }),

  mounted() {
    Promise.resolve(this.$store.getters.getUsersByTestId(
      this.$route.params.testId,
    )).then((value) => {
      this.users = value;
      this.import_complete = true;
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

Since it's a promise, I am setting a boolean import_complete to true, and a div in the template is only passing through the data as a prop when this boolean is true

Next, I am consuming the data in another template, in a for loop.

```html
<template>
<div>
  <v-container>
    <v-banner v-for="user in this.users" :key="user.index">
      {{ user.index }} {{ user.name }} {{ user.profile }}
      <template v-slot:actions>
        <router-link
          :to="`/usering/${user.test}/user/${user.index}`">
          <v-btn text color="primary">Open usering analysis</v-btn>
        </router-link>
        <v-btn text color="warning" @click="deleteUser(user.index)">Delete</v-btn>
      </template>
    </v-banner>
  </v-container>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

  name: 'UserList',
  props: {
    users: Object,
  },

  methods: {
    deleteUser(index) {
      this.$store.dispatch('delete_user', index);
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    console.log('mounted user list, here come the users');
    console.log(this.users);
  },
};
</script>
```

The thing is, the first time it doesn't show anything. Only when I make a tiny change in the last component (can be an Enter followed by a save command) and suddenly the users are displayed on the page.

Interestingly, in the first scenario, the user's array is already filled, I see it in the console (created in the mount method) as well in the Chrome developer Vue tab.

It's probably some kind of Vue thing I am missing? Does someone have a clue?

[edit]
I've changed the code to this, so directly invoking the localForage. It seems to work, but I would still like to understand why the other code won't work.

```
    this.test = this.$store.getters.getTestByTestId(this.$route.params.testId);

    this.test.store.iterate((value, key) => {
      if (key === (`user${this.$route.params.userId}`)) {
        this.user = value;
      }
    }).then(() => {
      this.dataReady = true;
    }).catch((err) => {
      // This code runs if there were any errors
      console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: hi, don't think so, but i must admit i am not very certain. I tried putting in a boolean v-if trick there as well, didn't work

Comment: Yeah, ignore my suggestion as it is far off

Comment: What does `this.$store.getters.getUsersByTestId(
this.$route.params.testId,
)` return? A Promise?

Comment: correct, a promise.

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem in my own attempt: [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-hellman-hq03m3?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: I just changed my code with this. Perhaps it's something linked to localForage, which is a async library i am using to store data in a browser session. Anyway, this works.... but still annoyed by the first attempt    this.test = this.$store.getters.getTestByTestId(this.$route.params.testId);

    this.test.store.iterate((value, key) => {
      if (key === (`user${this.$route.params.userId}`)) {
        this.user = value;
      }
    }).then(() => {
      this.dataReady = true;
    }).catch((err) => {
      // This code runs if there were any errors
      console.log(err);
    });

Comment: If you need help debugging code, then you will want to post a [mre] of it.